# Is it possible to validate a textbox to ensure that certain characters are used and in a correct sequence (e-mail address)?

Tags: c#, validation

I'm currently building a system that requires the user to enter an email address and to ensure that they don't just enter in any random array of numbers and letters, I would like something to validate it so that '@' and '.com' are used and in the correct order when they try to submit their details to a SQL database built within VS 2013.

Comment: Yes, it is emphatically "possible" to validate an email address using C#. As others have pointed out, there are many duplicate questions about this. But to answer your actual question: yes it is possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article [How to: Verify that Strings Are in Valid Email Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx) gives following regular expressions to validate e-mail address:

```
bool IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(StrInTextControl,
      @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
      @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
```

Comment: For future answers/questions please make sure to be very clear what code you wrote yourself and what code taken from other source (must provide clear link to original location for attribution). In this particular case answer is pointless as there is much better existing answer on SO (which you could have found and commented on the post instead).